# ExactTarget SOAP Client Using CXF

Tags: java, soap, exacttarget

I am looking to build a stand-alone ExactTarget SOAP client using CXF.

I was able to create a client using Glassfish Metro, but due to future support considerations we would like to use CXF. I found an old example and associated project, but it is too old to be useful.

Currently I am trying to understand how can I set a handler on the stub/port object and to pass dynamic username and password to it. By dynamic I mean: the app gets username and password from the user at the time of running. Here is the code that I currently have for the Metro implementation:

```
PartnerAPI service = new PartnerAPI();
Soap stub = service.getSoap();      
Map<String, Object> outProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();        
Map ctx = ((BindingProvider) stub).getRequestContext();

requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, user);
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);

List<Handler> chain = new ArrayList<Handler>();
chain.add(new SecurityHandler());
((BindingProvider) stub).getBinding().setHandlerChain(chain);
```

I am trying to reuse the first 4-6 lines for the CXF implementation, but I cannot use the handlers I have since they depend on `com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSProcessor`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that does everything:

```
private static Soap createApiStub() {
    PartnerAPI service = new PartnerAPI();
    Soap stub = service.getSoap();          
    Client client = org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(stub);     

    Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();        
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, username);     
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE,WSConstants.PW_TEXT);        
    // Automatically adds a Base64 encoded message nonce and a created timestamp
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ADD_UT_ELEMENTS,WSConstants.NONCE_LN + " " + WSConstants.CREATED_LN);    
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, new ClientPasswordCallback(username, password));
    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
    client.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

    //Enable GZip compression
    Map<String, java.util.List<String>> httpHeaders = new HashMap<String, java.util.List<String>>();
    httpHeaders.put("Content-Encoding",Collections.singletonList("gzip"));
    httpHeaders.put("Accept-Encoding",Collections.singletonList("gzip"));
    Map<String, Object> reqContext = client.getRequestContext();
    reqContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,httpHeaders);

    return stub;
}
```

And here is handler implementation:

```
public class ClientPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public ClientPasswordCallback(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, 
    UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for (Callback callback: callbacks){
            if (callback instanceof WSPasswordCallback){
                WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callback;              
                if (username.equals(pc.getIdentifier())) {                  
                    pc.setPassword(password);                   
                }
            } else if (callback instanceof NameCallback){
                throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callback);
            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callback);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11401154/1515058) helped me to pass the password dynamiclly.